# 64bit atomicAdd in CUDA

Tags: c++, types, cuda, atomic, word-size

I have a problem using `atomicAdd` under CUDA 7. `atomicAdd` is defined for "`int`", "`unsigned int`" and "`unsigned long long int`" stating it uses "the 32 or 64 bit value".

In our code we use `uint32_t` and `uint64_t` for safety. However gcc defines this in the following way:

```
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
typedef unsigned long int   uint64_t;
#else
__extension__
typedef unsigned long long int  uint64_t;
#endif
```

So when I pass an `uint64_t` to `atomicAdd` it complains because it is not defined for "`unsigned long int`".

Is it save to assume `uint64_t == long long int` for CUDA compilation as stated in the programming guide?

Comment: Yes me to. However it seems we encountered this earlier and defined (u)int64_cu for device side usage. Guarding that with a static assert is probably the best solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer that for future reference:

There are 2 options: Either use a typedef to define 64 bit cuda types like:

```
typedef long long int int64_cu
typedef unsigned long long int uint64_cu
```

And probably guard these by (boost-)`static_asserts` to be the same size(of)

Or as suggested by @Anastasiya Asadullayeva use a reinterpret_cast in the call which is better also guarded by a static_assert.